# Not getting notifications during the last days

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, notifications

During the last 3-4 days I am visiting the site and answering some questions, I have noticed that I am not receiving notifications(from the bar on the top, not email ones) for new answers in the questions I have answered.

Has anything changed and I am out of date or is it indeed a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get notifications for new answers to questions you've answered, just questions you've asked.  If you want to make it easy to find those questions, you can favorite them.

Comment: Note, though, that updates to favorited questions don't land in the top bar either.

Comment: Nice, haven't noticed that, what workarounds are available? for example if I answer 4 questions per day it is not handy to revisit them all, to check for updates?

Comment: @py_script I usually wait for a comment on my answer or keep 'em all open in tabs.

Comment: Ok, I have to admit it is not really handy for me. I may come back with a feature request. thanks for clarifying that. :)

Comment: @py_script each question also got an RSS feed (bottom right corner, above footer) so you can subscribe and using a feed reader see updates on the questions.

Comment: Yeah, thats better...